# How can I pass my public static files through my front controller via Nginx?

Tags: nginx

**Environment**

Nginx/1.14.0, Ubuntu 18.04

**Problem**

All the files that are not in my `/web` folder pass by my front controller but it is not the case for the ones that are in the `/web` folder. Why ?

My front controller is not reached so here is my Nginx configuration file (only showing the relevant part) :

```
root $rootPath/web;

# Handles rewriting
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

  fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
  fastcgi_param TEST_LOGIN yourLogin;
  fastcgi_param TEST_PASSWORD yourPassword;
}
```

Comment: The `try_files` statement will detect files that exist, and only if they **do not exist**, will internally rewrite the URI to `/index.php`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files). If you want every URI to be sent to `/index.php` including `.js` and `.css` files, use `rewrite ^ /index.php last;` instead.

Comment: I had made tests with `rewrite` and I then believe that it will change the url whatever I pass to the `rewrite` directive so I stopped testing this directive. Thanks :D